# Save failed with the following error: BLOB/TEXT column 'data' can't have a default value

Tags: php, joomla

I installed a Joomla 3.9.x template and updated to Joomla 4.0.2. (Varaham Education University from Themeforest) I also installed SP Pagebuilder Pro v3.7.14.

PHP Version: 7.4.23
MySQL Version: 5.6.41-84.1

---

Everything was working just fine until I needed to create a new Article. I had been using SP Page Builder to create new pages but I installed an image gallery plugin that requires it to be added to an article.

So I used the default Article feature on Joomla and when I tried to save it, the following message showed: Save failed with the following error: BLOB/TEXT column 'data' can't have a default value

Everything else works perfect on the website, I just cannot create a new article without getting this error.

I already looked on lots of websites and different search engines and have not seen a solution. Most similar results are just database talk and I was looking more for Joomla related solution.

I did go to the cPanel and did the "repair database" but nothing worked. I also went into phpMyAdmin and looked for a table with "data" to see if I could make some of the changes I saw others making in the database but did not find.

Most solutions out there are for you to fix the database and then reinstall everything. Unfortunately I have too much in the site where it would be hard for me to do it all over. My last resort would be to just nuke the site and start all over if I have to but this would set me back way too much.

PS>>> Perhaps someone can point me on how to create a new article via PHPMyAdmin without using the normal Joomla way to do it. (Found how to do it but the dates go back to 2011 and none for Joomla 4)

Comment: If you are a Joomla user, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

The error "BLOB/TEXT column 'data' can't have a default value" is the result of trying to create a new table.

```
CREATE TABLE banking.`TEST` (
  `str` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'blub',
  `lob` BLOB DEFAULT 'bla'
)
```

Remove the "DEFAULT"-definition at the BLOB-column and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE banking.`TEST` (
  `str` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT 'blub',
  `lob` BLOB
)
```

Comment: Would you mind clarifying this? Where would I look? Like I mentioned in my question, these are answers for non-Joomla situations. I do have access to the database but I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

Comment: Then there's might be a bug in something you've just added. If you've made recent changes [eg adding plugins or other non-standard code] try reverting them or seeing if there's a patch that fixes this issue. Otherwise you're likely going to have to bring in _paid_ outside help to look through your application to figure it out.